# Link non-spatial SQL Server query to a Geodatabase?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-engine, sql-server

Is it possible to build an object (of whatever kind) in ArcEngine code that links the geodatabase data with a non-spatial SQL Server query? How would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest Answer; [is to just create a data connection to your SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254953.aspx), Make your query and the returning dataset can be added to a [ESRI table in memory](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Converting_simple_data/00010000028w000000/) that you can join. 
 Once you have the data into a table in memory; you can join/relate or do whatever ESRI function you want to do.